# Посоветуйте сборку Linux'а для разработки по Android

Tags: android, linux, debian, ubuntu

Немного задрали уже и Windows и Ubuntu.

Может, кто посоветует православную сборку Linux'а, заточенную под Android разработку?

Условия:

1. Наличие в сборке Sun/Oracle JDK (OpenJDK, как известно, не дружит с Android).
2. Минимальные усилия по установке.
3. Желательно таки что-нибудь из дебиановского семейства.

Comment: Если вас "задрали" Windows и Ебунта, то не думаю, что вам вообще что-либо понравится )

Comment: Вообще я сомневаюсь, что такие есть. Что мешает jdk ручками поставить? Даже я с моей криворукостью это смог)

Comment: Самая лучшая сборка Linux - Mac Os X.
Не знаю ни кого из знакомых, кто перешел с Linux на Mac Os X, чтоб они вернулись обратно.

Comment: Mac OS - это Unix, но никак не Linux.

Comment: Но на столько хороший Unix, что не нужен больше Linux.

Comment: @Bimawa я б не согласился, ну да ладно.

Comment: Мне, например, нравится [Mint][1]. Ну а с JDK придется [помудохаца][2] вам в любом случае.

  [1]: http://www.linuxmint.com/
  [2]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre/55960#55960

Comment: Как ни странно, самый лучший именно Ubuntu. Почему? У него самый широкий комьюнити, а следовательно - большинство проблем уже решены, стоит только погуглить. По поводу JDK - я не верю, что у человека с 32к репутации тут руки не из того места растут, что бы [нагуглить][1], как удалить openJDK, и установить Oracle.


  [1]: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=ubuntu%20install%20oracle%20jdk

Comment: @metalurgus, а Вам не кажется, что смысл [ХК](http://hashcode.ru/) (и всех аналогичных форумов, например, [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/)) именно в том, чтобы не тратить свое время на гугл?

Comment: Бармалей, а чем-таки не нравится Ubuntu? Если не нравится оболочка Unity, то может, попробовать KDE или Xfce?

Comment: Речь не шла о том как поставить JDK - это действительно несложно. вопрос то был о другом:

>кто посоветует православную сборку Linux'а, заточенную под Android разработку?

Comment: @avp, нет, мне кажется, что смысл ХК в том, что бы найти тут ответы на вопросы, которые в гугле не отвечены. И мне не кажется, а это так и есть.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ "православную"?? ЛОЛ что? Отсыпьте и мне что ли...

Comment: @metalurgus, [только не уколитесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosa_Linux).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

1. http://bbqlinux.org/ Ребята посоветовали.
2. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2224142  - это еще нагугил. Неуверен, что по топику.

По поводу православного точно ничего хорошего нет. Всеже лучше Ubuntu пока, к сожалению, только Gentoo.

З.Ы. Юзабилити Mac Os X форева!!! Рвет убунту. Правда не из коробки, надо навесить многое. И лучше хакинтош, так как эпловское железо - го*но.

Comment: Да, BBQLinux очень похоже на то, что я искал - спасибо!

Comment: Только это ведь тоже не дебиановское семейство.

Comment: Посмотрел на bbq глубже... да там похоже обычный openjdk:)

Comment: Мне кажется, настроить BBQLinux будет уже проще, чем понерфить Ubuntu.

Comment: Легче будет настроить ту систему, которую знаешь. BBQ - неведомая поделка, поэтому мне лично будет легче настроить убунту (хотя я ее почти не использую) или федору/генту, чем разбираться с новым дистрибутивом, который "как бы заточен" (что уже намекает, что грабли красиво разбросаны).

Answer (score 4):

Ставьте тот дистрибутив, который Вам нравится, или у Вас есть знакомый гуру-админ, который его активно использует и готов помочь. Стандартная java пусть себе стоит, она никому не мешает.

Потом идете на сайт [оракла](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) и качаете 7 java. Оракл активно сейчас рекомендует 8, но на ее базе я не пробовал, потому пробуйте сами, если хочется.

Скачивайте `tar.gz` под Вашу битность системы. Архив распаковываете либо в домашний каталог, либо в `/opt`, который для этого хорошо подходит. Должен получиться где-то такой путь `/opt/jdk1.7.0_71/`. Скорее всего, распаковку в этот каталог нужно делать с правами рута.

Теперь нужно настроить IDE. Сейчас эклипс не модно использовать, и я его уже несколько лет не запускал, поэтому пишу для IDEA и AndroidStudio. Открываете в домашнем каталоге файл `.bash_profile` (если нет - создайте) и добавьте туда такие строки:

```
IDEA_JDK=/opt/jdk1.7.0_71
export IDEA_JDK
STUDIO_JDK=/opt/jdk1.7.0_71
export STUDIO_JDK
```

Сама IDEA и Android Studio при старте проверяют эти переменные, и если они выставлены - используют указанные.

Теперь либо перелогинтесь, либо перезагрузитесь. Но можно просто в консоли написать `source ~/.bash_profile`, но это подействует только на текущую консоль. Поэтому лучше перелогиниться.

А вот сам сдк я держу в домашнем каталоге, чтобы не иметь проблем с обновлением. Он находиться в каталоге `Android`, там же находиться и ndk. Чтобы утилиты запускались без проблем, я добавил ещё в `.bash_profile` строку

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Android/AndroidSDK:$HOME/Android/AndroidSDK/tools:$HOME/Android/AndroidSDK/platform-tools:$HOME/Android/AndroidNDK
```

После запуска IDEA или AndroidStudio они могут спросить, где java, которой компилировать андроид приложения (да, для работы ide и компиляции приложения могут использоваться различные версии java). В качестве каталога укажите `/opt/jdk1.7.0_71`, если только ничего не поменяли или версия jkd поменялась.

У описанного способа есть много плюсов:

- можно использовать несколько версий java для различных программ и даже проектов;
- можно не бояться, что после обновления системы все слетит;
- не конфликтует с другими приложениями, которые используют java;
- большинство админов поймет и одобрит эту идею.

Недостатки:

- относительная сложность первой настройки;
- сложность автоматизации обновления (на сайте оракла нужно соглашаться с скачиванием), можно качать со сторонних сайтов, но мало чего (особенно если режим паранои на максимуме);
- нужно обновлять пути в файле профайла (но можно создать ссылку и только обновлять ссылку).

Comment: @KoVadim, я не спрашивал о том, как настроить Linux под Android, а том, где найти сборку, где это уже готово в коробке...

Comment: А потом будете искать дистрибутив, чтобы он не только под андроид был заточен, а ещё и ..., и ..., и... (подставить нужное).

К тому же нормальный разработчик всегда должен уметь с нуля настроить себе рабоче место. Вон в Эппл принятого на работу сотрудника могут уволить, если он, получив рабочий ноут, не сможет настроить подключение к wifi (пароль дают) и почту. И правильно делают.

Разработчиков, которые себе не могут настроить окружение, тоже нужно выгонять. А поиск дистрибутивов, где все есть, - это обычная лень.

Comment: @KoVadim, уметь-то да, а вот разворачивать - нет. Я тут ноут думаю обновить, мысли о всем, что придется перелопатить, вызывают у меня боль. По-хорошему, конечно, идеально иметь собственный настроенный сценарий chef / puppet / saltstack, но его же еще надо поддерживать на каждый чих и новый пакет в системе, в общем, это и правда слишком болезненно и слишком много времени сливает впустую, чтобы не искать обходных путей.

Comment: @KoVadim, видимо у @Barmaley ♦ (или у его партнеров (клиентов)) есть организационные проблемы, раз он решил, что нужно взять решение "из коробки".

Эппл, наверное, может позволить себе такое отношение к сотрудникам, а вот тут и сейчас...

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ - у меня система переехала уже два ноута (то есть, уже на третьем) и на нем, на третьем, переехала на ssd. Также она живет с 12 федоры до уже 21 (просто обновляя). Все легко и не принужденно. Без боли.

Переезды занимают минут 20 работы + время на копирования разделов. Если переезд занимает больше - у меня тогда для Вас плохие новости:)

Comment: @KoVadim Я попробовал подевелопить на Android под Linux и немного был потрясен скоростью работы. Gradle + эмуляторы просто летают. Единственная боль которая осталась это настройка ее под себя - это действительно мазохизм. Даже установка Skype вызывает вопросы, не говоря уж о всякой мелочевке типа запуска x86 приложений под x64, проблемы с версионностями svn, шаманство с антиалисингом шрифтов и т.д. Подумываю перевести свой походный ноут под Linux.

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, а я попробовал подевелопить на Android на самом Android. Мне уже самого себя жалко.

Comment: @SuperCreeper расшифруй, а не догоняю. Жалко это как?

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, я имею в виду "мне жалко свои нервы". У `IDE` на Android мягко говоря кастрированный функционал, и в поисках нужного решения иногда приходится поизвращаться.

Comment: >  Даже установка Skype вызывает вопросы

скачать и запустить? да, 64битного скайпа нет (а то что на сайте - это 32битный с библиотеками в комплекте), но честно, настраивается просто - скачал, установил. Или просто репу добавляешь один раз и все будет.

проблем с svn никаких не видел.

> шаманство с антиалисингом шрифтов

поставить одну галочку?

Comment: @KoVadim научи :) Стоит Ubuntu 14 x64

Comment: я думал, что модератор, как никто другой понимает, что в комментариях подобные вещи не спрашиваются. А создаются отдельные вопросы, в которых все расписывается.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант CentOS:

1. Имеется.
2. Несложнее убунты.
3. Ubuntu и только ее, ну или сам Debian.

Сам ради разработки под android поставил Gentoo:

1. emerge dev-java/oracle-jdk-bin
2. gentoo handbook (чуть сложнее убунты).
3. Не Ubuntu.

Comment: CentOS на рабочей станции как не очень. В качестве сервера - да, весьма стабилен.

Comment: @skegg а чем он плох для рабочей станции? Конечно не gentoo, но постабильнее федоры, логичный и понятный дистрибутив, в котором все конфиги на своих местах, почти чистый redhat. Для любителей rpm-based самое оно. А любителям debian либо debian, либо ubuntu.

Comment: я лично по ряду причин предпочитаю, чтобы на настольной компьютере стояли более-менее новые версии программ (бывают исключения, но это исключения). CentOS принципиально содержит старые, но проверенные и стабильные версии.

Answer (score 1):

Сразу скажу, сам не пробовал, нашел в сети  [Oracle Linux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Linux),

он же [тут](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/2245947).

Правда, основан на Red  Hat (а значит ветка fedora а не debian).

---

М.б. еще стоит обратить внимание, что не так давно [Oracle отозвала лицензию  на поставку Oracle JDK в дистрибутивах Linux](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=31622). 
Е